# Django logging requests

Tags: python, django, logging

I'm using django 1.11 in `aws` elastic beanstalk and I've been trying to get my app to log with no luck . . .

I have these in my settings.py

```
LOGGING_CONFIG = None
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/opt/python/current/app/staging.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
import logging.config
logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
```

then I try to call one of my API and expecting something would show up in the log but it didn't. I `django.request` logger supposed to automatically log all incoming request or do I have to create a middleware that does `logger.debug('something')`?

logging in django is a lot more complicated than I thought :(

Answer (score 16):

Django logger extensions work differently in development than in production (settings.DEBUG=True|False).

What you expect to see - http request logs - are written by *django.server* logger,
which is active only in development server (runserver command).

I see that in your configuration you use *django.request* logger. This logger name is very confusing - because as its name suggest - users will expect it to log all http requests - but it won't.

*django.request* will log only 4xx and 5xx requests.

I've made a [screencast](https://www.django-lessons.com/lesson/lesson-3-django-logging-requests) which explain this issue in detail.

[Django documentation about loggers.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/logging/#id3)

Comment: Fiefox does not allow to openthe screencas link for security reasons i.e. the certificate is not trusted.

Comment: I'm flabbergasted by the fact that the Django documentation for the `django.request` logger does not mention the fact that it only logs 4xx and 5xx. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Firefox doesn't open the screencast link above on MacOS and on Chrome a message is shown that my computer is locked due to unauthorized access and that a trojan virus is detected.

Answer (score 8):

demo of logging in django,log is location in `/path/to/your/project/log/info.log`,
your need to create info.log in log/ dir first.

settings.py

```
LOG_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "log/")
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s]- %(message)s'}

    },
    'handlers': {
        'django_error': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': LOG_PATH + 'django.log',
            'formatter': 'standard'
        },
        'info': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': LOG_PATH + 'info.log',
            'formatter': 'standard'
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'info': {
            'handlers': ['info', "console"],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['django_error', 'console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        }
    },
}
```

the effect of loggers is:

- info: your custom debug info
- django: the request record
- django.request: the error request
- django.db.backends:Messages
  relating to the interaction of code with the database

more info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/#id3)

views.py

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("info")
logger.info('something')
```

you will get

```
2017-08-31 13:05:40,492 [INFO]- something
```

in log/info.log later.

Answer (score 0):

In production, I handled this outside of Django by modifying my `gunicorn` command:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:4000 --access-logfile - my_project.wsgi
```

The `--access-logfile` [parameter](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#accesslog) controls which file `gunicorn` will log the info to. It defaults to `None`. If you set it to `-`, it'll log to stdout.

If your app is behind a reverse proxy (e.g., Nginx), `gunicorn` will log the proxy's IP by default. You can tell `gunicorn` to log the `X-Forwarded-For` header instead, which represents the real client IP:

`--access-logformat '%({X-Forwarded-For}i)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"'`

*(Beware that there are security concerns when reading X-Forwarded-For. See [this article from HTTP Toolkit](https://httptoolkit.com/blog/what-is-x-forwarded-for/) for more details.)*